# Async method with no await vs Task.FromResult

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Consider the following interface:

```
public interface IProvider
{
    Task<bool> Contains(string key);
}
```

This is implementation satisfies Visual Studio

```
public Task<bool> Contains(string key)
{
    return Task.FromResult(false);
}
```

This implementation is *convenient to write* and would seem to achieve the same thing:

```
public async Task<bool> Contains(string key)
{
    return false;
}
```

However, Visual Studio throws a hissy-fit and insists:

> This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await TaskEx.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

I'd love to just ignore that warning and avoid using `Task.FromResult(...)`.

Are there any negative consequences to using the latter option?

Comment: Why? Using `Task.FromResult()` is the correct call since your code *doesn't* do anything asynchronously. `async` doesn't make something run asynchronously, it's just syntactic sugar that allows you to `await` already asynchronous operations. Using `async` just to return `false` is not convenient anyway, it's *more* verbose than simply returning the `Task<bool>` instance.

Comment: BTW what's the point of this code? Why use tasks if you don't intend to run anything asynchronously? Why not just write a `public bool Contains(..)` ?

Comment: Your first implementation is only returning a `Task<TResult> and does noting asynchronous.`. Your second implementation is marked with `async` and your are not executing any async running task. Off course your get an warning. BTW: Your interface and your methods have different count of parameters. Are you sure you implemented this interface?

Comment: Generally speaking this is a so called 'async over sync' antipattern that should be avoided. We haven't really seen any `async` operations here why would you want to create a state-machine only for your 'little convenience' when you can simply return a `Task` by yourself ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I think this is the use case for `Task.FromResult`. When the interface allows asynchronous callers, but the implementation is synchronous.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - you don't get much choice if someone else defined `IProvider` and you're trying to implement it.

Comment: @ChristianMurschall Fixed thesignature mismatch, this was just sample code, not a real-world implementation. :) And thanks for recognizing this as a legitimate question rather than dismissing it as "you are wrong in having this problem in the first place". :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason for that "hissy fit" is that the compiler needs to do a *lot* of work to present a task that works in all the expected right ways here, which you can see [by compiling and decompiling it](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQDABCCMDcCwAoEBmKAmCBhCBvJEhUaIAHFNAKwB0IAbADwBGA9iwDYB82LAdgC4BDAJa8AzgAoYkANYBTAJ4AaCpDEBjFgAc5ASgJF8iIiagB2CADNB7MXITGiAXyROgA)

`Task.FromResult` is cleaner, but may still have overhead - IIRC there are some scenarios where a `Task.FromResult` might work efficiently here (returning the same object each time), but I wouldn't rely on it.

There are 2 pragmatic reliable approaches:

- return a reused static `Task<bool>` result each time
- use `ValueTask<bool>` - which seems ideal here if you are returning synchronously a lot of the time

i.e.

```
private readonly static Task<bool> s_False = Task.FromResult(false);
public Task<bool> Contains(string key, string scope)
{
    return s_False ;
}
```

or

```
public ValueTask<bool> Contains(string key, string scope)
{
    return new ValueTask<bool>(false);
}
```

Note: the second of these may not be possible in this case, since you didn't define the interface. But: if you ever *are* designing an interface that needs to allow async usage but which may actually be sync: consider using `ValueTask<T>` as the exchange type, not `Task<T>`.

The generated C# of:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> Contains(string key, string scope)
{
    return false;
}
```

is something like:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)]
[CompilerGenerated]
private struct <Contains>d__0 : IAsyncStateMachine
{
    public int <>1__state;

    public AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<bool> <>t__builder;

    private void MoveNext()
    {
        bool result;
        try
        {
            result = false;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            <>1__state = -2;
            <>t__builder.SetException(exception);
            return;
        }
        <>1__state = -2;
        <>t__builder.SetResult(result);
    }

    void IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext()
    {
        //ILSpy generated this explicit interface implementation from .override directive in MoveNext
        this.MoveNext();
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    private void SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine)
    {
        <>t__builder.SetStateMachine(stateMachine);
    }

    void IAsyncStateMachine.SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine)
    {
        //ILSpy generated this explicit interface implementation from .override directive in SetStateMachine
        this.SetStateMachine(stateMachine);
    }
}

[AsyncStateMachine(typeof(<Contains>d__0))]
public Task<bool> Contains(string key, string scope)
{
    <Contains>d__0 stateMachine = default(<Contains>d__0);
    stateMachine.<>t__builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<bool>.Create();
    stateMachine.<>1__state = -1;
    AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<bool> <>t__builder = stateMachine.<>t__builder;
    <>t__builder.Start(ref stateMachine);
    return stateMachine.<>t__builder.Task;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, especially the insight into what happens behind the scenes of an apparently simple piece of code. It's easy to forget at times how much is going on down in the depths of the CLR. :)